# Why does the logical statement !0x00 return 0x01 in C?

Tags: c

I'm reading Computer Systems a programmers perspective, and I'm getting into logical operators, which are similar to bitwise operators, but with a few differences.

What I CANNOT figure out is that when you have a logical operand !0x00 returns 0x01 rather than 0x11?

! is NOT, right? So NOT 0(false) should be 1(true) and another NOT 0(false) should also be 1(true) as well, right?

I look at the bitwise operator example : ~00, naturally that would return 11, but C's logical operators seem to work with vast differences.

Why does this happen?

What I have tried already: Reading a little further to find the answer I seek, it doesn't seem to be here.

What I think the problem is: Might have something to do with how Hexadecimals work? But, Hexadecimals can still have 0x11. . . .

Comment: It's evaluated as a boolean value. `0` is false, `1` is true. `!false`, then, must be `true`.

Comment: Don't confuse `!` (logical negation; yields `0` [false] or `1` [true]) with `~` (bitwise negation).

Comment: Even thought an if statement for instance will treat a zero value as false and anything else as true, logical operators like &&, ||, <, >, <=,>=, ==, !, and != evaluate to 1 for true and 0 for false regardless of if some non one true value was passed or anything

Comment: why would it return 0x11? do you mean 0xff?

Comment: So you know there are bitwise and logical operators. You also know these are different. Then why would you expect them to work the same way?

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline Okay, I get 0 is false 1 is true. What I do NOT get is why does !(NOT)x00 give 0x01 rather than 0x11? NOT 0x(False)(False) should return 0x(True)(True), right? Why does it return 0x(False)(True) or 0x01 ?

Comment: @pmg I didn't confuse logical negation with bitwise negation. . . I even pointed out the differences to illustrate WHY I'm asking? WTF?

Comment: So if zero is false, and you apply a logical not operation to it, you get one out, which is true. I'm not sure I follow the question. The base of the number isn't important.

Comment: 0x11 is actually 17 decimal 0x means hexadecimal not binary.

Comment: @dangee1705 Because according to the book, logical negation returns 0 for false or 1 for true. Any argument 0 is false. Any nonzero argument is true.  What I am asking is why do these LOGICAL ARGUMENTS !0x00 return 0x01? Is it perhaps because 0x00 is a WHOLE argument and 0x01 represents TRUE for the entirety of the hexadecimal argument?

Comment: @cleblanc Dude, I never said it was binary. . ..  .What?

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline okay, we have !0x00, right? So, ignoring a base we have NOT 0 0, right? That's TWO zeroes. So, why am I getting 0x01? or 01 RATHER THAN 11 when I have 00?

Comment: @The_Senate If you understand that true is 1 you understand why it's not 0x11

Comment: Ah, I see the confusion. The number of zeros doesn't matter to the operator. Think of them as left padded zeros in decimal -- 0005 is still just 5. So when you give it 0x00, it just sees 0 and returns 1.

Comment: @ReticulatedSpline so if I had !0x9001 it would return 0x01 as well, because 1 is true, and 0x01 is just a fancy representation to indicate that there is 1 and therefore true?

Comment: No, any non-zero value is true, so !0x9001 would return 0 for false. Might make more sense in decimal, I think you're getting caught up on the hexadecimal notation. `0x9001` is 36865 in base 10.

Comment: right, right brain fart. I understand now. Thank you, that's all I wanted.

Comment: Also, considering logical and bitwise operators similar is a fundamentally mistaken viewpoint imo.

Comment: `~00` does not "return" `11`

Answer (score 6):

Because that's how the language is defined. `!` is the logical NOT operator and boolean logic in C works on `1` and `0`, representing `true` and `false`.

C17 6.5.3.3:

> The  result  of  the  logical  negation  operator
>   !
>   is  0  if  the  value  of  its  operand  compares
>   unequal to 0, 1 if the value of its operand compares equal to 0. The result has type
>   int.

You can think of it as if returning `bool`, though it actually returns `int` for backwards-compatibility reasons. Unlike C++ where it does return `bool`. The same goes for relational and equality operators.

Comment: So, it's more akin to a bool function than a bitwise operation? With 0x00 being false and 0x01 being true? You know, I used to hate discrete structures but it has become SUCH an asset in learning computing principles.

Comment: @The_Senate The "logical" part in the operators name refers to boolean logic.

Comment: Yes, yes. . . It's all making so much sense now! Thank you, Lundin.

Answer (score 2):

The expression `!n` is equivalent to `(n==0)`. It returns `1` if true, `0` if false.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `!0x00` nor `~0x00` will give you `0x11`.

`!n` is the same as `n==0` and evaluates to `1` or `0`.

`~n` negates the bits of the binary representation, not the digits of the literal you chose to enter the number.

Comment: They were using shorthand to mean `~0x000000... = 0x111111...`. Note that they didn't specify the `0x` part either.